# GXT - Pissed off with ComobBox in Grid (different Display Label and Value)

Tags: gwt, gxt

I am trying to add a CobmoBox in EditorGrid
I have a class Vehicle with fields 
Integer vehicleId;
String plateNo;
Integer vehicleType; //1=Car,2=Truck

I want the combo box to show vehicle's type in text form i.e if vehicleType is 1, "Car" would be displayed. And when the user select any other option - like "Truck"  the corresponding integer value should be populated into the bean.

This is pretty standard stuff with plain old JSP and HTML. 
However I couldn't find a simple way the do this in Ext GWT.

Comment: Can you upload some of th editable grid code or the method you are using to populate the store.

Comment: May be this link can help you otherwise you can include Gwt-Ext or SmartGWT  [http://code.google.com/docreader/#p=google-web-toolkit-incubator&s=google-web-toolkit-incubator&t=PagingScrollTable]

Answer (score 0):

If you are using a GXT ComboBox, the easiest way to is create a model representing your vehicle object if you haven't already.  This is basically a class that extends GXT's BaseModelData class.

Once you have your model, you create a combo box using that type:

```
ComboBox<VehicleModel> box = new ComboBox<VehicleModel>();
```

The last step is to tell the combo box which fields to use for values and for display, which is done with 2 method calls:

```
box.setDisplayField("field name for display");
box.setValueField("field name for value");
```

When you load up a store of vehicle models, GXT will take care of the rest.  You will, however, need to convert the model back to the vehicle object itself to be persisted.